# Set the price by calling another contract and getting result from it

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, oracles, external-api, price

I want to set the price in **Token** every time the contract is deployed by calling **ETHUSD** in constructor and getting result from it.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

import "./ETHUSD.sol";

contract Token {

    uint256 public price;

    constructor() public {
        price =
    }
```

> What should I add in **Token** after "**price =**" to make it work?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

    import "./oraclizeAPI.sol";

    contract ETHUSD is usingOraclize {

        string public priceETHUSD;

        event LogNewCoinBaseOraclizeQuery(string description);
        event LogNewCoinBaseTicker(string price);

        constructor() public {
            oraclize_setProof(proofType_Android | proofStorage_IPFS);
            update(); // Update price on contract creation...
        }

        function __callback(bytes32 _myid, string memory _result, bytes memory _proof) public {
            require(msg.sender == oraclize_cbAddress());
            update(); // Recursively update the price stored in the contract...
            priceETHUSD = _result;
            emit LogNewCoinBaseTicker(priceETHUSD);
        }

        function update() public payable {
            if (oraclize_getPrice("URL") > address(this).balance) {
                emit LogNewCoinBaseOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was NOT sent, please add some ETH to cover for the query fee!");
            } else {
                emit LogNewCoinBaseOraclizeQuery("Oraclize query was sent, standing by for the answer...");
                oraclize_query(5, "URL", "json(https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/ETH-USD/ticker).price");
            }
        }
    }
```

*Contract above **ETHUSD** is just example and it gets the price from the API.*

Answer (score 1):

```
price = ETHUSD(0x123abc...).priceETHUSD();
```

Replace `0x123abc...` with the actual address of the deployed ETHUSD contract you want to use.

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Should go ahead and accept that answer @3rr0r

Answer (score 0):

@UP

That’s works and it’s gets the specific price from the „*0x123abc...*” address contract.

> But how I can get „*0x123abc...*” address field automatically updated
>   every time I call the Token contract?

What I mean by that that is:

> Token **=>** call ETHUSD **=>** ETHUSD is deployed and ***new
>   address*** is generated **=>**  Token
>
> price = ETHUSD(***new address***).priceETHUSD();